# Maven shade jar throw exception

Tags: maven, exception, maven-shade-plugin

I have the following Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest
>   section for      signature file entry
>   javax/security/cert/CertificateException.class
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:380)
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:231)
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:176)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:288)
>           at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:199)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:323)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:388)
>           at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:692)
>           at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:61)
>           at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:144)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:256)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       Could not find the main class: com.mainClass. Program will exit.

My pom:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filter>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of java version.
I didn't notice that my new ide automatically use ibm's java, when I change the jre to sun's java ,it works well:)

Answer (score 27):

The `SecurityException` comes up because one of your dependencies is a signed jar.
As the shade plugin is repacking this jar, it gets invalid. -> `SecurityException` at launch

To solve the problem, you have to *unsign* the dependency jars while repacking them.
This can be done by simply not repacking the files that make the jar signed, using a filter:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>stand-alone</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>stand-alone</shadedClassifierName>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <!--
                            Exclude files that sign a jar
                            (one or multiple of the dependencies).
                            One may not repack a signed jar without
                            this, or you will get a
                            SecurityException at program start.
                        -->
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude> <!-- This one may not be required -->
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This solution was extracted from here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-61

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the stacktrace above says

> Could not find the main class: com.mainClass.

Perhaps a typo in the classname or the class is not compiled before the plugin in invoked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's the name's problem. Or it should give exception as noclassdeffoundexception.