# How can I exclude *.DSA and *.SF files from shaded jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a section in pom.xml

```
 <filters>
   <filter>
      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
         <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
         </excludes>
   </filter>
</filters>
```

I want to exclude *.SF and *.DSA files from final jar.
But I get the following message:

```
[INFO] No artifact matching filter *:*
```

and files are not excluded.
Does anyone know how to overcome it?

Comment: Related: [Maven shade jar throw exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8302022/320399)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It was fixed by making my artifact selector more specific, e.g.

```
<artifact>bouncycastle:*</artifact>
```

The entire block looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>bouncycastle:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
```

Comment: Tried that (without ManifestResourceTransformer), didn't work for me, the BCKEY.* files are still there. I've tried artifact `*:*:*:*` too. It's an old answer, has Maven syntax changed since?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, did you find a solution. Above solution doesn't work for me?

Comment: Moving configuration out of executions did the trick for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740005/673826

Answer (score 14):

Actually you can do global filtering without needing to specify group id, you just need to use the correct wildcard syntax.  If you want to exclude all *.RSA files from your jar, for example, specify the artifactId as `*:*:*:*`

```xml
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*:*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.RSA</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

Comment: It doesn't exclude `META-INF/ECLIPSE.SF` and `META-INF/ECLIPSE.RSA`. What's even more interesting is that I'm not using eclipse at all, I'm using Intellij.

Comment: This allowed me to remove a pesky license.txt file from the jar by just including the line <exclude>LICENSE.txt</exclude>

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but neither of the answers worked for me. Combining them did:

```xml
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*:*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```