# NoClassDefFoundError for springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

Anyone familiar with this runtime exception?

I have built a jar which tries to instantiate a bean based on an application-config.xml.  It looks like the bean gets instantiated, well the ctor gets called but shortly after I get the below exception.

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingRebinder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:525)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.blark.migration.adr.RetentionADRTool.bootstartToolBean(RetentionADRTool.java:110)
at com.blark.migration.adr.RetentionADRTool.initTool(RetentionADRTool.java:84)
at com.blark.migration.adr.RetentionADRTool.countTerminatedOrgs(RetentionADRTool.java:100)
at com.blark.migration.adr.RetentionADRTool.main(RetentionADRTool.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I use maven to build my applicaitom.

Here is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>ark-migration</artifactId>
<name>Retention Migration Tool</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.blark</groupId>
    <artifactId>retention</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bl.wx3</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bl.wx3</groupId>
        <artifactId>conversation-db</artifactId>
        <version>${conversation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>retention-migrations</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <target>
            <echo message="Running retention schema migrations..."/>
            <java jar="${project.build.directory}/migration.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="update_schema"/>
                <arg value="retention"/>
            </java>
            </target>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>migration-tool</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/migration.jar</outputFile>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.blark.migration.RetentionMigrationTool</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!--
                                    Exclude files that sign a jar (one or multiple of the dependencies).
                                    Repacking a signed jar without may cause the program to throw a SecurityException at launch.
                                    See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302022/maven-shade-jar-throw-exception for more details
                                -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>retention-adr-tool</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/retention-adr-tool.jar</outputFile>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.springframework.retry:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.freemarker:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.bl.webex.apis:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.bl.oauth2:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.sun.jersey:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.sun.jersey.contribs:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.blark.migration.adr.RetentionADRTool</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Add your POM to the question.

Comment: I added the pom

Comment: Darren, you asked for the pom, are you able to take a look for me?

Comment: Also need that parent. It looks like you're trying to run a spring boot app but dependencies are not there.

Comment: I am going to take a different approach, but from my debugging I think you are correct that dependencies are missing. Thaks for your help.

Comment: The issue lies somewhere in your parent or how you've defined your boot application. Normally you do not need to specify the logging starter as it is generally pulled in by other starters.