# Is it a requirement to use signed JARs?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am building a shaded jar from dependencies and while using this shaded jar, I came across this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest
>   section for signature file

**I was able to fix it** by excluding the signed jars from shaded jar and using those jars directly but I came across following SO questions on the same topic:

[Maven shade jar throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302022/maven-shade-jar-throw-exception)

[How can I exclude *.DSA and *.SF files from shaded jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658831/how-can-i-exclude-dsa-and-sf-files-from-shaded-jar)

["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)

[Valid JAR signature for JavaFX projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842559/valid-jar-signature-for-javafx-projects)

which suggest that we can resolve the problem by excluding the files that sign these jars.

But my question is, is that the right and **legal** way ? For example, one of the signed jars that I was using was `mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7.jar` signed by Microsoft. Microsoft must have signed it for legal and/or security reasons.

Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "right and legal"? Do you mean whether you will violate licenses and possible go to jail?

Comment: I was not thinking that extreme but what I fail to understand is that when there is a way to use an unsigned version of same jar why did the company sign it in the first place?

Comment: @theLearner To make sure it is created by the company. If you repackage it, you can't keep the signature.

Comment: @lexicore ok and whether I can repackage it or not will depend on the license, right? For e.g. if a jar has an apache license, I can repackage it.

Comment: @theLearner IANAL and won't comment on the Apache License. But, generally, yes, you have to consider licenses, especially when you repackage or redistribute anything.

Comment: If a package is already Apache Licensed why do you need to repackage it? Does not make sense...just use it as a dependency...

Comment: One more thing.. If you create a shaded jar you already violating the integrity of the single jar files which them self have checksums and signatures...If this is legal for this question you should ask a lawyer in particular related to those files from Microsoft etc.also for the other files...

Comment: @khmarbaise I used **Apache** just for an example. Could you please elaborate **violating integrity of a single jar**